# Drupal and Apache Solr connections over http

Tags: search

I have installed Apache solr on a VPS. I am trying to connect Drupal 7 using the apachesolr module by specifying 
    `http://128.199.174.33:8080/solr` 
as the Solr Server URL. But my site is unable to contact the Solr server.

I should mention that these two servers are in different regions of the world and I am attempting to connect using http. The solr server has no iprules or other firewalls that block incoming connections.

(I am able to connect drupal to apache solr if they are on the same machine.) I am not sure if there is anything worng but it just doesn't seem to connect.

Comment: Er, you realise I (or anyone else) could just go and delete all of your cores now right?

Comment: No issues. Its just a test VPS. No sweat.

Comment: Gotcha :) The correct URL to give Drupal will be http://128.199.174.33:8080/solr/CORE_NAME, if that doesn't work check you're not blocking _outgoing_ connections from the client machine

Comment: @Clive You nailed it I had missed the CORE_NAME

Comment: Funny, Now Tika doesn't seem to work or rather Drupal solr_attchments module is not able to recognise tika on the remote solr server.